# Change Recyclerview row design when swiching between LayoutManger types (Grid - Linear)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to learn more about **RecyclerView** and its implementations, so in this case I need to to design tow item views, one will show when LayoutManager is **LinearLayoutManager** which in this case will show a vertical List of cards, the second item design will be used when changing LayoutManager to **GridLayoutManager** type.

> my question is how to implement such logic?

I read some answers here, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) about Recyclerview with multiple row design but found nothing about switching between LayoutManager types.
and according to this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs_C1E8HwvE) we shouldn't play with layout manager in Adapter.

finally I have to mention that I'm new to Android development so I hope my question is clear, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna change between vertical linear layout and grid (vertical) layout, just use `GridLayoutManager` and change the column span between 1 (vertical layout) and a value higher than 1 (for grid).

You can use different span values for different layouts using the layout qualified resource folders.

For instance, imagine you want vertical linear in portrait and grid in land:

```
int spanCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column_count);
return new GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount);
```

Then create `values/integer.xml` and `values-land/integers.xml` where you will define `column_count` with the different values.

Answer (score 1):

you can create both layout managers and set the right manager to your RecyclerView in the activity and not the adapter according to a certain condition (screen orientation for example):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView
    int numberOfColumns = 3;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,numberOfColumns);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_view_recycler)
    if (condition){
      mRecyclerView.setLayouManager(mLinearLayoutManager)
    } else {
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager)
    }
```